# Acer Aspire V5-575 Wifi Issues

Tags: 12.04, wireless, acer, aspire

I recently bought an Aspire A5-575 laptop which works great, the only issue I'm having is with the Wifi.

It seems to have a hard time connecting, and then will randomly disconnect. When it's connected everything's fine and I get a great signal.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and not sure if it's related to

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this, the link to the Realtek driver in the comments seemed to work - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/998200